# How to add a millisec of time to this epoch?

Tags: javascript, unix, time, momentjs, epoch

`1474148715` According to [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) it's: `GMT: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 21:45:15 GMT`

Trying [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/guides/), but no luck:

`const startMomentized = moment(Date($state.params.start_epoch)).add(1, 'milliseconds').unix();`

^ This gives me the date: `GMT: Thu, 09 Feb 2017 19:39:43 GMT` instead of the date in Sep 2016, I'm trying to have.

---

Hoping for something like the following:

```
var start = params.start_epoch;
var startUpdated = start+millisec;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value represents time in milliseconds since 1970. You can add milliseconds directly to that number like: `1474148715 + 1`

Comment: Lol thanks that was it! I was trying to overcomplicate this... another 10 mins :)

Comment: @LeonGaban Actually user Void is correct, you have time in seconds, not milliseconds. You need to multiply it by 1000 before adding a millisecond to it. That epoch converter website you linked takes seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Ah thanks, for the purpose of my logic tho... we're using the start_epoch to help create a unique id for this object. So both 1 millisec or 1 sec would work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add Milliseconds directly to the value you have

```
var newDateTime = new Date(1474148715*1000+1);
```

Don't forget to multiply the value with `1000` to convert in milliseconds.